# How to decode a json.dumps from python in Processing?

Tags: python, json, processing, osc

I have a python OSCclient that sends a json.dumps(dictionary) to a OSCP5 server in Processing (Java Mode).

python side:

```
'input_dict = {'text': 'Dies ist der erste Kommentar', 'cat': 'insinuation',   'category_counter': {'praise': 0, 'insinuation': 1, 'dissence': 0, 'lecture': 0, 'concession': 0}, 'is_locked': False}
data = json.dumps(input_dict)
client.send_message('/display_input', data)
```

The message is being sent and received, but there seems to be a problem with decoding the json data in the function oscEvent.
Processing Side:

```
void oscEvent(OscMessage m) {
  print("### received an osc message.");
  print(" addrpattern: "+m.addrPattern());
  println(" typetag: "+m.typetag());
  if (m.checkAddrPattern("/display_input") == true) {
      println("INCOMING :", m.arguments()[0]);
      JSONObject new_utt = loadJSONObject((String) m.arguments()[0]);
```

processing prints out:

> received an osc message. addrpattern: /display_input typetag: s

> INCOMING : {"text": "Dies ist der erste Kommentar", "cat": "dissence", "category_counter": {"praise": 0, "insinuation": 0, "dissence": 1, "lecture": 0, "concession": 0}, "is_locked": false}

> The file "{"text": "Dies ist der erste Kommentar", "cat": "dissence", "category_counter": {"praise": 0, "insinuation": 0, "dissence": 1, "lecture": 0, "concession": 0}, "is_locked": false}" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.

my question: is there a way to send jso.dumps via OSC to Processing where I can open them as JSONObjects?

Comment: Seems like someting is interpeting the JSON as a filename

Comment: Awesomeness!  parseJSONObject did the trick. Thank you @user202729 also thanks everybody for their comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`loadJSONObject`](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html) interprets its argument as a file name that points to a JSON file.

To parse JSON from a string, use the function [`parseJSONObject`](https://www.processing.org/reference/parseJSONObject_.html) instead.